# How to Get Rid of Aggressive Ground Bees

Tags: pest-control

What is the easiest and safest way to get rid of very aggressive ground bees?  I am not able to mow the lawn or doing any gardening around my flower bed at the front of my house, as these bees will sting and there are many of them.

Comment: Ground bees? Are you talking about black and yellow striped wasps also known as Yellow Jackets which live in underground paper nests? Or Digger/Mining Bees which nest in tubular holes in the ground?

Comment: How long have they been there? I did a little research based on @FiascoLabs comment and both Digger Bees and Miner Bees have fairly short periods of activity during the year. They're also both mentioned as being mostly non-aggressive unless you step right on their holes, so that's another point in favor of Yellow Jacket wasps.

Comment: I believe this is a type of hornet.  Are they small, golden?  I've stood next to a 'kill', some rabbit or small mammal and...this was amazing...I had these small hornets get under my shirt and in my hair and it was like the leader said...'ON THE COUNT OF 3'...they all stung at the same time!  Not a pretty moment in my life...got to the emergency room with anaphalactic shock and doctor took 47 stingers out of me.  Do not! use machinery anywhere near!!  I'd allow a few weeks and if they are still around perhaps do what Michel advises.  Usually short term habitation.

Answer (score 3):

The two solutions I've used in the past are avoidance and hot soapy water. Where I live at least, wasps use abandoned ground squirrel tunnels, but they use them for one year only. If you can avoid entering the area around their nest for the rest of the season, the problem will go away on its own.

If that isn't a possibility, pour a large bucket of soapy water down the hole after dusk, quickly cover the hole and leave. In my experience, this is as effective as wasp/hornet spray and you don't have to worry about harmful chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

One successful method that I have used is to wait until dusk when the bees are not active, pump a generous amount of wasp/hornet spray into the hole, put a rock over the hole, wait of few days.  This worked every time I tried it.